# How to redirect to new page(along with model) on JQuery ajax call in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have forgot password page, where the user enters the username and clicks the 'Validate' button to check which group he is in. Based on the group we need to display the different partial views (for now let's say it is phone number) in the page. After filling the valid details, **on success I will redirect to a new page where he will update his password, on Failure, I need to show the error message.**

Now I have a hard time in writing the code for highlighted.

Here is the code for Jquery ajax function which trigger on submit button click

```
person = {UserName: $("#UserName").val(), Phone: $("#Phone").val() }
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Customer")',
            data: person,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                //This is the place I need help
                if(data.IsDataValid){
                  // redirect to new page passing the model object
                }
                else{
                    //Show an error message without hiding the div
                }
            },
            failure: function () {                   
            }
        });
```

Here is the code Controller Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(true)]
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword(RegisterModel model)
    {            
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            Here is the logic which validates the user
            return Json(new { regmodel = RegistrationModel })
        }
    //If it is not ajax call I want to return the view
        if (isUsergroup1 == true)
        {
            return View("View1", RegistrationModel );
        }
        else if (isUsergroup2 == true)
        {
            return View("View2", RegistrationModel );
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `IsDataValid` a property of `RegistrationModel`?

Comment: @Tieson Yes, but again as I addressed to your answer, I also need to pass the model to the controller

Comment: Mixing Javascript inside a view? **Gives me creeps**. I suggest you rather use `data-` attributes to pass over particular URLs in your view and read them in a script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we need to do. We can't pass the model, we can only pass the parameters in the redirection of a link. And we must use link.replace as you can pass the variables directly into the Url.Action

```
person = {UserName: $("#UserName").val(), Phone: $("#Phone").val() }
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Customer")',
        data: person,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //This is the place I need help
            if(IsDataValid){
              var link = "@Url.Action("Actionname", "Controllername", new { username = "1", phone ="2" })";
                   link = link.replace("1", data.username);
                   link = link.replace("2", data.phone);
                   alert(link);
                   window.location.href= link ;
            }
            else{
                //Show an error message without hiding the div
            }
        },
        failure: function () {                   
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't know if you saw the comments on the question above, but it looks like the conditional should be `if(data.IsDataValid){ ... }`. I just didn't bother to update my answer at all...

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the part of your question that is answerable right now:

```
if(IsDataValid){
  // redirect to new page(
}
else{
    //Show an error message without hiding the div
}
```

To redirect, use `window.location.replace('url to new page');`.

For the "error message" part, I would either use jQuery UI to display a dialog, or have a hidden div that you insert error messages into, perhaps like so:

```
$('#errors').html(data.Errors).show();
```

This assumes you have some sort of property called `Errors` that contains validation messages on `RegistrationModel`.

Comment: To redirect I can use that, but the problem here is I need to pass the model object along with it.

Comment: @user1678741 - you can't pass the model object with a redirect, at least not without serializing it to the url querystrings, which you probably don't want to do.